# Getting numbers when iterating through XML HTML object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am getting a series of numbers iterating through a javascript object and I am trying to understand why.

Here is my code:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "https://rsshub.app/instagram/user/jasminealkouri/", true);
x.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
    {
        var doc = x.responseXML;
        var titleArray = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel")[0].getElementsByTagName("title");

        for (var prop in titleArray) {
            var webString = webString + "<br>" + prop;
        }


        document.getElementById("mainP").innerHTML = webString;
    }
};
x.send(null);
```

The output I get is:

```
undefined
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
length
item
namedItem
```

The first line of `Undefined` I understand, but the rest I have no clue why it's being represented.  I looked online and can't find anything.  If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, and you're iterating over all properties of this object. What you probably want instead, is iterating over all elements. In that case a `for` … `of` loop should do.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over an array and printing out the index of that array.
You should be doing something like

`var webString = webString + "<br>" + titleArray[prop].innerHTML;`

Try doing a console.log on `titleArray` before the for loop to understand the element you're looping on.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `for key-in-obj` loop. Go through these documents **[for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** and **[for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)**

`for key-in-obj` gives index of obj not value.

```
    for (var prop in titleArray) { // prop here is index not value at index
        var webString = webString + "<br>" + prop;
    }
```

Replace it with:

```
for (var prop of titleArray) {
    var webString = webString + "<br>" + prop;
}
```